# text with .fyi attachment

Tags: virus

I occasionally get texts from numbers I don't know.  My standard procedure is to delete and not give it another thought. Lately, I have received texts with attachments that look like this; Tap to load preview fkhlkf.fyi

What is a .fyi attachment and is it potentially dangerous to my phone?

Carol

Answer (score 1):

There are no common file types with the extension ".fyi", but I suspect that the real extension is hidden somehow; it may well be a malicious APK or similar.

As-is they pose no threat to you unless you try to open them.

My advice would be to continue what you're already doing - delete the message and block the number if possible.